# Emoji output: xterm escape sequence oddity?

Tags: unicode, terminal, emoji, windows-terminal

I have a .NET Core app. The only thing it does is:

`System.Console.Out.WriteLine("\x1b%G");`

When I run this on a "fresh" Powershell tab in Windows Terminal, it outputs

`??`

When I run it a second time in the same tab, it correctly outputs:

(ramen emoji)

Running the same line twice in one process does not work - it's `??` twice.

(If I don't include the `\x1b%G` escape sequence, it 'never' appears as a ramen emoji)

### What I'm trying to do

Work out what it is that "enables" emojis for a terminal (be it Windows Terminal, the new conhost in Windows 11, etc).

I thought it might be `\x1b%G`, the xterm escape sequence to enable UTF-8. Maybe it is? ...but why not until the process exits and is started again in powershell?

### Other notes

If I don't use a blank Powershell profile, but instead use one that gives fancy prompts (`Set-PoshPrompt -Theme powerlevel10k_rainbow` for instance)... then emojis are "activated" / "enabled".  So maybe there's something that Powershell, or posh prompt does, that I can replicate?

### The correct answer to this question will...

...tell me what I need to do to have emojis correctly appear in my terminal, without having to run the process twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set the output encoding thusly:

`System.Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`